# Testing dygraphs with Selenium

Tags: selenium, dygraphs

My project has just applied dygraphs. http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/linear-regression

I already went around but I could not find out my needed answer. Please help to advise me

1. Is it possible to test dygraphs using selenium?
2. Is selenium the best way to test dygraphys? In case it's a NO, which is the most suitable tool to test dygraphs

Thanks,

Comment: can u tell as what are u verifying in dygraphs? And possibly a working code snippet to show us the problem?

Comment: http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/linear-regression such as this one. I need to verify all points

Comment: In that what would you like to verify? can u give us a scenario? if you want to verify the result value appearing at the top of the graph something like Y1:Y2, then that can be verified provided you know the expected result